# Django FilePathField filter used entries

Tags: python, django

I have the following Model where the FilePathField should be unique:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    template = models.FilePathField(path=".../templates/galleries/", unique=True)
```

In the admin, I would like the dropdown list to only show me those entries that have not been used, yet, in order to make the selection among available answers more easy.

After all, any already used option in the resulting dropdown list will give me an error anyway and does not need to be shown to me in the admin. Unfortunately I am having problems wrapping my head around this.

Can anyone tell me where I could insert something similar to the following:

```
used = [gallery.template for gallery in Gallery.objects.all()]
return [file for file in files if file not in used]
```

...or might I have overseen an option somewhere in Django that could already give me the desired result? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the field "template" should be unique, the resulting dropdown list in the admin should only display those files in the specified location, that have not been entered in any other entry in the database.

Comment: So, lets say, I have two template files "a.html" and "b.html" in my location ".../templates/galleries/". After I create a first entry with "a.html" set as template in the Gallery model, the admin to create a second entry into Gallery should not show me "a.html" in the dropdown list for template anymore, because the field is unique and selecting "a.html" would only result in an error anyway. Additionally, it would free up the dropdown list only showing me the valid templates I could choose from. I hope this example clears it up a bit more! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of digging, I managed to come up with a solution myself. Ill post it here as an answer if anyone seeks a similar solution:

Extend a ModelAdmin for your Model and implement a new get_form() method that takes the choices of your named FilePathField and filter this list to your liking.

Ill give an example for the Gallery Model above:

```
class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        used = [gallery.template for gallery in Gallery.objects.all()]
        form = super(GalleryAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['template'].choices = [choice for choice in form.base_fields['template'].choices if choice[0] not in used]
        return form
```

EDIT: I noticed this prevents you from changing an entry, as the option originally set will now be removed. I managed to get this to work with this small tweak:

```
class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj: # we are changing an entry
            used = [gallery.template for gallery in Gallery.objects.all() if gallery.template != obj.template]
        else: # we are adding a new entry
            used = [gallery.template for gallery in Gallery.objects.all()]
        form = super(GalleryAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['template'].choices = [choice for choice in form.base_fields['template'].choices if choice[0] not in used] 
        return form
```

Hope this may help anyone in the future!